# Getting a DateTime value inside a remote event reciever will be different than the one the user enters

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, remote-event-receiver

I am working on an online SharePoint site collection, which have the following regional settings:-

[image]

and I hosted a remote event receiver inside azure web app,where the remote event receiver will get fired when adding/updating list item. now inside the remote event receiver i have the following code to get a DateTime value named ApproveDate:-

```
DateTime approveBy = (DateTime)projectItem["ApproveDate"];
```

but if the user enter a value for the ApproveDate equal let say `30/09/2020` inside the SharePoint form as follow:-

[image]

then the DateTime value inside the remote event receive will be `9/29/2020 8:00:00 PM` instead of `9/30/2020 00:00:00 AM`.. so why i am facing this issue? is this because the azure web service have different time zone compared to the SharePoint site? and how i can fix this?

Comment: Maybe be because your list column [Approve By] is collecting time-part of the date entered. If you don't care about the time part, set "Date and Time Format" of list column [Approve Date] to "Date Only"

Comment: Also, SharePoint internally stores DateTime in UTC format, so in your code you could convert it to any time zone

Comment: @MatiurRahman it is already date only, but internally SharePoint will add the time at midnight

Comment: @MatiurRahman can you advice more on this please? so this is not related to where i host the remote event receiver inside azure? but rather related to sharepoint which will always store the time in UTC format regardless of where the azure web app is hosted or the regional settings for the site collection?

Comment: SharePoint is always going to store Date and Time in UTC. However, when you view it in browser, it converts to browser's time zone. I'm not sure about code running in azure, but you can convert it from UTC to your desired time zone. See here how to convert: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @Matiur Rahman i think when we view the sharepoint form in the browser it will show the date based on the site collection time zone and not based on the browser time zone!!

Comment: Yes, when lists in site collection are viewed in browsers, date time fields are rendered in local time zone. However, when you read the same column in code or in MS Flow, by default it returns in UTC. For example, 9/21/2020 6:52 PM (Eastern USA) shown in the browser, but in MS Flow the same field value is returned as 2020-09-21T22:52:00Z (UTC)

Comment: @MatiurRahman no when the date time fields are rendered in the browser they are rendered in the regional setting for the site collection...

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Never had to set the regional setting for site collections, maybe because for on-premise default is automatically set to the server's regional setting.

Comment: @MatiurRahman So the question is when i get the time inside my remote event receiver it will be based on the regional setting for the site collection or based on the location/time-zone of the azure web app?

Comment: Date and Time still stores in UTC in SharePoint stores, so when you read that in code, it returns in UTC as you can see in my earlier example.

Comment: @MatiurRahman so this will not depend on the site regional setting or on the azure web app location? now in my case it is hard to guess as the azure web app's time zone is also UTC..